# Open a webpage with certain x y coordinates

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, coordinates

How can I use JS or CSS to open a webpage to automatically scroll to a certain XY-position on it? As a background: There is a grid out of 5x5 elements and I want the center of that grid to be the center of the viewport when the page loads. So the 3rd element in the 3rd row of the 5x5 grid should be the center.

Any ideas?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Combine `window.onload` and `window.scrollTo`:

```js
window.onload = () => window.scrollTo(/*x coord*/, /*y coord*/);
```